# External HD doesn't respond when plugged into computer

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have an external harddisk. When I plug it in the computer, the computer will show nothing (even not show extra partition at all) but the light of the harddisk is lit up.
The harddisk is a Samsung G2 portable.

Comment: Are you using Windows? Is it a new hard drive? Has it worked before? What do you expect to see? Do you see the icon for the hard drive when you go to Computer, or My Computer? You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify OS, but I'm going to assume Linux is available to you (use a LiveCD if you need to)

Check:

- `fdisk -l`
- `cat /sys/block/*/device/model`
- `dmesg`
- `lsusb`